# Why quasi-random sequences are generated in the interval [0,1]? Is it a normalized sequence generation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, random, algorithmic-randomness, quasigroups

The quasi-random sequences are generated using low discrepancy sequences and Koksma-Hlawka inequality explains the quasi sequence clearly. However, it is observed that these sequences are generated in the range [0,1]^s always, where s is the dimension. Can anyone please explain why is the sequence generation always in the range [0,1]? Is the sequence generated a normalized one?

Comment: Since we can transform a random variable in $[0,1]$ into any continous random variable (for example a normal distributed random variable), we only need a generator for $[0,1]$

Comment: In support of @Peter's answer, see for example the book *Automatic Nonuniform Random Variate Generation* by Hörmann et al.